# Task 'wrapper' not found in project ':app'. when trying to import spring dependency

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I have a gradle project in intelliJ using the Java 8 JDK. The project runs fine until I try to add a spring dependency (I've tried spring boot starter and spring context).

**build.gradle**

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 */

plugins {
    id 'closet.java-application-conventions'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-text'
    implementation project(':utilities')

    implementation 'com.jfoenix:jfoenix:8.0.9'

    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-context:5.3.2'
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClass = 'closet.app.App'
}
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8-all.zip
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

When I try to build I get the error `Task 'wrapper' not found in project ':app'` where app is the name of my module.

If I change `https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8-all.zip` to `https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8-bin.zip` then it builds successfully, but it doesn't seem to add spring to the classpath as I can't access annotations like `@Component` or others.

What's the problem here?

Comment: What does `closet.java-application-conventions` do?

Comment: @BjørnVester I'm not sure, this was the code gradle generated when I used unit to generate a multi module project (this is the build gradle of one module, there is no parent build.gradle and settings.gradle just lists the module names). How/where can I find what that plugin is doing?